# Is really SAFE_CAST is helpful to clear errors?

Tags: sql, database, casting

If CAST function fails it returns an error in BigQuery. To avoid any error we use SAFE_CAST.
My question is that SAFE_CAST hide the error of SQL queries.Using,
SELECT SAFE_CAST(MyDate AS STRING)FROM MyTable

SAFE_CAST is hidden all the CAST errors.